# PSCredential variable stops working for WinRM function after being passed to get-winevent

Tags: powershell, authentication, winrm

I am seeing WinRM Client errors when reusing a Credential object, but only if I'm using it on `Get-WinEvent`, before I used it on `Get-WindowsFeature`.

If I replace the `Get-WindowsFeature` with an `Invoke-Command` calling `Get-WindowsFeature` against the server and using the same credentials object then things work as expected, but that causes other issues with different parts of my script, and I'd rather understand why it's not working.

I've stripped things down to the bare minimum to demonstrate the error and got to this.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

$Name = "server01"

Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName $Name -Credential $Cred 

Get-winEvent -ComputerName $Name -Credential $Cred -MaxEvents 1

Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName $Name -Credential $Cred
```

**Expected Results**

List of Windows features and their status on server01

The most recent event log entry on server01

List of Windows features and their status of server01

**Actual Results**

List of Windows features and their status on server01

The most recent event log entry on server01

`Get-WindowsFeature : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Requests must include user name and password when Basic or Digest authentication mechanism is used. Add the
user name and password or change the authentication mechanism and try the request again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName $Name -Credential $Cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsFeature], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.GetWindowsFeatureCommand`

Comment: have you tried re-ordering the requests to see if it's winevent or if it's clearing the $cred variable?  I'd also maybe add a line above each one `$cred2 = $cred` and replacing all the $cred variables with $cred2.  Just some thoughts, i'm not sure the issue at play.  Also you don't need creds if you're running as an admin with priveleges for the server...  it's the last command with issues. Maybe put a 3 second pause between the last 2 commands? I also noticed you're not specifying a logname. could be server01 has a max tries per minute

Comment: @RobertCotterman the variable isn't being cleared. I can continue to use the $Cred variable for other commands, just not get-windowsfeatures, so using it to call get-winevents or get-wmiobject etc. works fine even when get-windowsfeatures is failing. I can't see any sign of throttling and sadly the functions I'm building can't be garanteed to be running with local admin rights on all targets.

Comment: I also tried the $Cred2 = $Cred you suggested and $Cred2 fails in the same way. I'd guess it's one of those times when PS is just creating a reference to the initial variable rather than creating a true copy. $Cred.PSObject doesn't have a Clone method unfortunately.

Comment: I bet the remote machine is limiting log in attempts per second, minute or hour. Those commands you posted will happen in rapid succession.

Answer (score 0):

why not try this instead

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

$Name = "server01"

invoke-command -ComputerName $Name -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {

    Get-WindowsFeature

    Get-winEvent -MaxEvents 1

    Get-WindowsFeature

}
```

Comment: That will absolutely work and get around the issue for the example, sadly it won't work in the context I'm actually running the Cmdlets where they're part of nested custom functions. I can work around it by just changing the order I'm calling the functions for now, but there's clearly something going on that I don't understand so I'd rather get to be bottom of it than have it bite me unexpectedly later.